# How to set extension enable and disable

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions

Have an extension and want to enable it if `$field1 == $field2` and if not extension be disable.

can enable it with line below but can not disable it when if is not true!

```
protected function _beforeSave()
{
    $value = $this->getValue();
    $fieldConf = $this->getFieldConfig();

    if ($value) {
        try {

            $fields2 = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/module/fields2');
            $fields1 = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/module/fields1');

            $condition = empty($fields2) || !$fields2 || empty($fields1) || !$fields1;

            if ($condition) {
                $err = Mage::helper('module')->__('extension not registered.');
                Mage::throwException($err);
            }

            if($field1 == $field2) {
                Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('carriers/module/active', 1)->reinit();
                Mage::app()->getConfig()->reinit();
            } else {
                Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('carriers/module/active', 0)->reinit();
                Mage::app()->getConfig()->reinit();
                $err = Mage::helper('module')->__('Is not valid and Disabled.');
                Mage::throwException($err);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::throwException($e->getMessage());
            return $this;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that determining whether to enable or disable an extension in the method logic is a good approach.

The extension you want to enable or disable should have an entry point, at which it checks for your `$field1 == $field2` condition. If it it holds true, it should go on with its processes; otherwise, it should just return.

If you *really* need to do this "on the fly," I suggest checking `$field1 == $field2` **right after** Magento either loads the cached configurations or loads them all at once with something like..

```
Mage::getConfig()->setNode($nodePathToYourExtension, 'false', true)
```

Offhand, it should be somewhere in `Mage_Core_App::run()`.

Comment: I want to disable it because if for first time `$field1 == $field2` be true, extension will be active and after that if `$field1 != $field2` then extension will be enabled and value of active remain 1

Comment: You can do still do that via the entry point method.

Comment: can you please explain more about your method ?